# Running Docker compose with ElasticSearch on OS X gives me error sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When running Docker on my my OS X i get the following error:

**sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count": Read-only file system**

I know on Linux you can use edit sysctl but i haven't worked out how to do this on OSX. Ive tried setting Docker for Mac memory under preferences but that didn't do anything. I tried the screen command as well but to no avail.

Comment: What is the exact command that you are running when you get this error message? What is the context that you are running the command in? from inside a container? from your OS X host? somewhere else?

Comment: I'm running it inside a container and running compose up which has a bunch of commands inside

Answer (score 2):

I am just guessing here but are you setting up Elasticsearch?  They have explicit instructions for OSX here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html

From the above:

> The vm_max_map_count kernel setting needs to be set to at least 262144 for production use. Depending on your platform:
>   ...
>    OSX with Docker for Mac
>
> The vm_max_map_count setting must be set within the xhyve virtual machine:
>
> `$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty`
>
> Log in with root and no password. Then configure the sysctl setting as you would for Linux:
>
> `sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`

If this isn't quite what you're looking for, can you paste your exact input and output of the command?

Comment: Having the same issue, that isn't working for me. And I also cannot enter the container via ssh as elastic is not actually starting